# python web2py controller request.vars doesn't have attribute (but actually does)

Tags: python, web2py

Python 2.7.12

web2py 2.14 stable

--call to controller developed by javascript

--call to controller.  Captured by Chrome inspect

```
GET "http://127.0.0.1:8000/default/FoldBe.html?operation=get&id=%23"
```

--controller default.py

```
FoldBe():
    vars = dict(request.vars)
    print type(vars)
    #<type 'dict'>

    print vars
    #{'operation': 'get', 'id': '#'}

    for i in vars:
        print i
        #operation
        #id
        #print i.id

    print vars.id
    #ERRORS!!! stating.  What gives?
    #<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> 'dict' object has no attribute 'id'
```

But the 'vars' dict obviously is a 'dict' and obviously has an 'id' attribute
If i remark out `print vars.id` the view renders in the browser & no errors indicated as you would expect.

If I allow `print i.id` to execute the error is:

```
<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> 'str' object has no attribute 'id'
```

What gives?

I have other methods in this controller and other controllers where this isn't a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should access dictionary keys by name, so try `vars['id']` instead of `vars.id`.

Comment: oddly I thought I tried that.  But you are correct.  maybe I confused vars[id] and missed using the 'id' semiquotes